# Robust Local Optical Flow (RLOF) coordinate in output are not correct (doc SparseRLOFOpticalFlow)

Tags: python, opencv, opticalflow

I try to use the opencv librairy of the Robust Local Optical Flow (RLOF) function (https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/d84/group__optflow.html). To do this, I use the FAST function of opencv to extract the different characteristic points of the video (frames). The size of my video is 640*480 with 30 fps. Then, I use the FAST function in my main function on frame n and frame n-1 All through the video. Then, I use the RLOF on characteristic point detect with FAST function on image n et image n-1 function with the different parameters I could find by reading the documentation of this algorithm.

Moreover, between each frame, I don't have exactly the same number of characteristic points detected, so I think that's why the option `setUseInitialFlow(True)`, brings me this opencv `cv2 error. error: OpenCV(4.4.0) /tmp/pip-req-build-b_zf9wbm/opencv_contrib/modules/optflow/src/rlofflow.cpp:372: error: (-215:Assertion failed) nextPtsMat.checkVector(2, CV_32F, true) == npoints in function 'calc'`.

My code works, my variable keypoints_old contains this as coordinates found with FAST (more than 500) :

```
keypoints_old = 
[[250.   3.]
 [400.   3.]
 [411.   4.]
 ...
 [360. 465.]
 [607. 466.]
 [519. 471.]]
```

But, the coordinates I find with the RLOF function to find the amount of motion between the two images for the following image are not really consistent. In the opencv documentation, I'm supposed to get point coordinates from it. Maybe, I think, these co-ordinates represent the quantities of movements, but, reading the documentation, it's not supposed to be that.

```
keypoints_new = [[-1.0420260e+20  4.5582838e-41]
 [-1.0420260e+20  4.5582838e-41]
 [ 3.5204788e-38  0.0000000e+00]
 ...
 [-3.5464977e-24  4.5582838e-41]
 [-3.5465167e-24  4.5582838e-41]
 [-3.5465356e-24  4.5582838e-41]]
```

My question is, how use correctly this function RLOF ? Why the coordinates of found points of the 2nd image are not logical with the coordinates of the previous image (the 1st) ? What's wrong with my code ? Thanks you for your answer.

My function :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import os
import argparse
import re
import os
import argparse

def FAST(img):

    # Initiate FAST object with default values

    fast = cv.FastFeatureDetector_create()
    keypoints = fast.detect(img,None)
    pts = cv.KeyPoint_convert(keypoints)
    return pts

def RLOF(old_frame, new_frame, keypoints_old, keypoints_new):

    # Parameters for RLOF

    instance = cv.optflow.RLOFOpticalFlowParameter_create()
    # instance.setUseInitialFlow(True)
    instance.setMaxIteration(30)
    instance.setNormSigma0(3.2)
    instance.setNormSigma1(7.0)
    instance.setLargeWinSize(21)
    instance.setSmallWinSize(9)
    instance.setMaxLevel(9)
    instance.setMinEigenValue(0.0001)
    instance.setCrossSegmentationThreshold(25)
    instance.setGlobalMotionRansacThreshold(10.0)
    instance.setUseIlluminationModel(True)
    instance.setUseGlobalMotionPrior(False)

    keypoints_new, st, err = cv.optflow.calcOpticalFlowSparseRLOF(
        old_frame,
        new_frame,
        keypoints_old, None, rlofParam = instance,
        forwardBackwardThreshold = 0)

    return keypoints_new

def __main__():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some video.')
    parser.add_argument('file_path', type=str,
                    help='Video_file path')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    video_file = args.file_path
    cap = cv.VideoCapture(video_file)
    fps = cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    frame_count = int(cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    ret, new_frame = cap.read() # 0
    ret, new_frame = cap.read() # 1
    p1 = FAST(new_frame)
    print('frame_count = {}'.format(frame_count))
    while cap.isOpened():
        for i in range(frame_count):
            old_frame = new_frame # 1 2 3 4
            p0 = p1
            ret, new_frame = cap.read() # 2 3 4 5 ..
            if ret:
                p1 = FAST(new_frame)
                RLOF(old_frame, new_frame, p0, p1, i)
            else:
                cap.release()
                break
__main__()
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the images you use for tracking?

Comment: @TobiasSenst Refer to https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/2663#issuecomment-1337491740. I also get strange results.